# Spinner with Key-Value Pair

Tags: android, spinner

I am working on multi languages UI. My requirement is in spinner I want to show data in Hindi but when it will be selected it should return english show it can compare to further decision making. Just like  tag with  tag.

My java code is something like this

```
    HashMap<String,String> options=new HashMap<String,String>();
    String optionsEnglish [] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option_array);
    String optinsHindi[]= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option_array_hindi);

    for(int i=0;i<optionsEnglish.length;i++)
    {
        options.put(optionsEnglish[i], optinsHindi[i]);
    }
    Spinner optionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.optionPicker);


    ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    dataAdapter.add(options);


    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    optionSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

In xml

```
    <resource>       
            <string-array name="option_array">
                  <item>Market</item>
                  <item>Commodity</item>
            </string-array>

            <string-array name="option_array_hindi">
                  <item>बाजार</item>
                  <item>वस्तु</item>


            </string-array>

     </resources>
```

Comment: so what is u r problem ??

Comment: I am not getting drop-down of two option बाजार, वस्तु instead of i am getting {Market-बाजार, Commodity-वस्तु} printed as only one option

Comment: i want two option with lable बाजार, वस्तु and when बाजार will be selected market should return and when वस्तु selected commodity should return so i can make proper decision for the some action on itemSelected event

Comment: see as i know this feature of key /value  is not available in Android .so for the same i have implemented  the code that i have posted use that code might help u.because me to have the same requirement i have done like this

Comment: Why can't you set the text in spinner's onItemSelected() method.?

Comment: I've needed this as well and set up a simple library that does just that -- Spinner with keys and values: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-KeyValueSpinner

Comment: Best Approach for key value using spinner : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner/37046661#37046661

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this can help you

Add Data in in **Spinner**

```
private void setDataInSpinner(Spinner id, int dataArray) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, dataArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        id.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

To get the **selected** value of Spinner use this

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Or You can use **setOnItemSelectedListener**  to get the selected values

```
String value = GetClassCode.getCode(Text);//here u have to pass the value that is selected on the spinner
```

Create a **Class**

```
public class GetClassCode {
    static HashMap<String, String> codeHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        init();
    }

    public static void init() {
        codeHash.put("key", "value");
        codeHash.put("key", "value");
        codeHash.put("key", "value");
        codeHash.put("key", "value");

    }

    public static String getCode(String param) {
        return codeHash.get(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting how to add it to spinner can us give me the complete code

Comment: see on the selection of the spinner get the data pass to the function GetClassCode in that codeHash hash set the key as  बाजार and value as Market so when he will select the बाजार  this class will return Market it very simple

Comment: have u got or still any issue

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From your code the getCode(param) will return null only because for a hashMap get(param) method returns the value of a hashmap provided the param is key. So for getting the key the method should be public static String getCode(String param) {
  for (String keyVlue : codeHash.keySet()) {
   if (codeHash.get(keyVlue).equals(param)) {
    return keyVlue;
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

Answer (score 9):

Step 1 : Create **POJO** class which will take care of key and value

```
  public class Country {
      private String id;
      private String name;
      public Country(String id, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
     }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    //to display object as a string in spinner
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Country){
            Country c = (Country )obj;
            if(c.getName().equals(name) && c.getId()==id ) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

  }
```

Step 2 : Prepare data to be loaded in spinner

```
private void setData() {

        ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Add countries

        countryList.add(new Country("1", "India"));
        countryList.add(new Country("2", "USA"));
        countryList.add(new Country("3", "China"));
        countryList.add(new Country("4", "UK"));

        //fill data in spinner 
        ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countryList);
        sp_country.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp_country.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(myItem));//Optional to set the selected item.    
    }
```

Step 3 : and finally get selected item's key and value in onitemselected listener method of spinner

```
sp_country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 Country country = (Country) parent.getSelectedItem();
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Country ID: "+country.getId()+",  Country Name : "+country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {    
            }
        });
```

Comment: but its show a whole array on dropdown like this : DepartmentSel(id=5, name=DepartmenName)

Comment: @haidarvm, add this  //to display object as a string in spinner
       @@Override //skip one @ 
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

Answer (score 2):

You made two separate string array for language words like in given xml ,right?
then just use ArrayAdapter for first option array and set adapter in spinner. and on select of any item of spinner according to it's position fetch world from second string array..

it will be quite easy and also work for more then 2 languages.

Answer (score 2):

I created an HashMap [adapter](https://gist.github.com/6e8dcf689be7cec89579.git) that might help.  Also see example project [here](https://github.com/ayvazj/hashadapter-android)

```
    mapData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    mapData.put("shamu", "Nexus 6");
    mapData.put("fugu", "Nexus Player");
    mapData.put("volantisg", "Nexus 9 (LTE)");
    mapData.put("volantis", "Nexus 9 (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("hammerhead", "Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE)");
    mapData.put("razor", "Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("razorg", "Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile)");
    mapData.put("mantaray", "Nexus 10");
    mapData.put("occam", "Nexus 4");
    mapData.put("nakasi", "Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("nakasig", "Nexus 7 (Mobile)");
    mapData.put("tungsten", "Nexus Q");

    adapter = new LinkedHashMapAdapter<String, String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mapData);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit old question, but this is in the top answers when searching from google.

I used this method:

Get the localized value from the spinner:

```
String localizedValue = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)).getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then get the key dynamically from string resources file:

```
String key = (String) getResources().getText(getResources().getIdentifier(localizedValue, "string", "my.package.name"));
```

All languages should contain the key for the localizedValue in strings.xml:

```
बाजार=Market
```