# Android SQLite: Spinner + select sql methods

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have a Spinner which is showing SQLite data. For that I am using this select method:

```
public List<String> getAllProductsName(int id)
{

    String buildSQL = "SELECT nome FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Produtos.TABELA + " WHERE id =" + id;


    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            nomes.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return nomes;
}
```

The thing is, I am getting only the names but I need the ID as well. I know i could use **"SELECT nome, _id FROM "**, but how would I return that? Could i possibly return 2 lists (one with IDS and the other one with the Names) in the same method?

Or maybe I should create a new method that show the Names only (when i give the ID as a parameter)? Please help! thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ... using and returning **HashMap** that contains *ID as keys* and *nome as values*

```
public HashMap<Integer,String> getAllProductsName(int id)
    {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT nome,_id FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Produtos.TABELA + " WHERE id =" + id;


        HashMap<Integer,String> idAndNomes = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                idAndNomes.put(cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(0)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return idAndNomes;
    }
```

Then you can use:

`idAndNomes.keySet()` - Returns a set of the keys contained in this map. In our case **ID**.

`idAndNomes.values()` - Returns a collection of the values contained in this map. In our case **nomes**.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! I just have one last question, how could I use this with the adapter I'm using for my spinner? Will i have to create a hasmap adapter or is there one already?

Comment: Here is exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner