# Set value for Spinner with custom Adapter in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am developing a android application with spinner in a form. **The spinner items and spinner values are different.** I want to collect all the value from the from including spinner and set a rest api service to web back end.

here is the response array.

```
{"Status":true,"errorType":null,"countryList":[{"Code":"US","Name":"United States"},{"Code":"CA","Name":"Canada"},{"Code":"AU","Name":"Australia"},{"Code":"GB","Name":"United Kingdom"}]}
```

I am successfully binded the **Name** jsonObject to spinner but I cant add the **Code**.

here is my code.

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(res);
            String status=responseObject.getString("Status");
            JSONArray JA = responseObject.getJSONArray("countryList");
            JSONObject json= null;


            if(status.equals("true")) {

                final String[] str2 = new String[JA.length()];
                for (int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    str2[i] = json.getString("Name");
                }

                sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citnzshp_field);
                list = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
                {
                    list.add(str2[i]);

                }
                Collections.sort(list);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
                adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);

                sp.setAdapter(adp);


            }
```

How can I bind the **code** jsonObject to spinner for taking after form submits.

Can anyone please share me the advantage of making custom adapter for binding data to spinner and selecting value also.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner/24712664#24712664

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Haresh Chhelana example is good, However if you want to show both name and code in spinner after selecting, check this out.

```
    List<Map<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
        json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
        mapData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapData.put("name", json.getString("Name"));
        mapData.put("code", json.getString("Code"));
        items.add(mapData);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {
            "name", "code" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And Spinner selected item callback

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Map<String, String> selectedItem = (Map<String, String>) parent.getSelectedItem();
                String name=selectedItem.get("name");
                String code=selectedItem.get("code");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: @bharath, why this code is not working for autocompleteTextView

Comment: For autocomplete textview you can display only one value for that reason i guess.

Comment: yea. but want to take another value for api. same as the above scene. is it possible..

Comment: no bcz above adapter uses `R.layout.simple_list_item_2` which has two TextViews in it.. in your above case you need to use custom adapter...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81169/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-bharat).