# Best practice to implement key-value pair in android Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to implement an android spinner with key value .

> en:english   jp:japanese

And when user select and item I want to save key to database . And also on next load I want spinner to select a particulate spinner position.

Can any one please tell me what is the best way to implement this.

I have tried following but doesn't met my requirement 
https://gist.github.com/granoeste/2786663
[Set Key and Value in spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner/24712664)

Write now I am using LinkedHashMapAdapter. But issue is that here I need to store position in DB or local shared preference . I don't think this a better solution

Current Implementation

```
LinkedHashMap localeList = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> val : map.entrySet()) {
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(val.getValue(), "string", getPackageName());
            localeList.put(val.getKey(), getResources().getString(resourceId));

        }
        LinkedHashMapAdapter<String, String> arrayAdapter = new LinkedHashMapAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, localeList);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        mLocale.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        String localPosSelected = PreferencesHelper.getSharedPreferenceString(this, Constants.PREF_LOCALE_POS_KEY);
        if(localPosSelected!=null){
            mLocale.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(localPosSelected));
        }
```

Also is there an option to selected item of Spinner by value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

setup Spinner:

```
        spLang = (Spinner)view.findViewById( R.id.spLang );
        spLang.setOnItemSelectedListener( this );
        ArrayList<String> sp_Lang = new ArrayList<String>();
        sp_Lang.add("english");
        sp_Lang.add("french");
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sp_Lang);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spLang.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

For Perticular Spinner item Selection:

```
int Position = spinnerAdapter.getPosition("Japanese");
spLang.setSelection(Position);
```

First Create Hashmap for store Key and value pair

```
HashMap<String ,String> hmLang = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Now Add value like this into HashMap :

```
hmLang.put("english" ,"en");
```

Here in HashMap key = YourValue and Value = yourKey

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch(adapterView.getId())
    {
        case R.id.spLang:
        String lang_Name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        String lang_Key = hmLang.get(lang_Name);
        break

    }
```

If you have any issue with this code then please ask

Comment: Can you please consider this scenario . I saved JP in database . And in next load i want JP(Japanese) to be pre selected in spinner .

Comment: Please check my Updated Answer and go ahead If this answer helpful then give vote.

Comment: are you suggesting me to maintain both ArrayList and HashMap ?

Comment: for selection just put this code
int Position = spinnerAdapter.getPosition("Japanese");
spLang.setSelection(Position);

Comment: There are Hashmap used for get key of Selected Item from Spinner.

Comment: currently i am using LinkedHashMapAdapter is there any option to get position here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103695/discussion-between-rahul-and-dhaval-jivani).

Comment: 简述：监听到spinner选择之后，获取这个值，去查哈希表

Answer (score 5):

I created using  an [HashMap](https://gist.github.com/ayvazj/6e8dcf689be7cec89579) adapter for use in these scenarios. Also see example project [here](https://github.com/ayvazj/hashadapter-android)

```
  mapData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    mapData.put("shamu", "Nexus 6");
    mapData.put("fugu", "Nexus Player");
    mapData.put("volantisg", "Nexus 9 (LTE)");
    mapData.put("volantis", "Nexus 9 (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("hammerhead", "Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE)");
    mapData.put("razor", "Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("razorg", "Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile)");
    mapData.put("mantaray", "Nexus 10");
    mapData.put("occam", "Nexus 4");
    mapData.put("nakasi", "Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)");
    mapData.put("nakasig", "Nexus 7 (Mobile)");
    mapData.put("tungsten", "Nexus Q");

    adapter = new LinkedHashMapAdapter<String, String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mapData);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: I tried to use this but could you please tell me how to get key and value of selected item . And also how to set a spinner with a particular value

Comment: Can you please consider this scenario . I saved JP in database . And in next load i want JP(Japanese) to be pre selected in spinner .

Comment: ~ @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> item 
  = (Map.Entry<String, String>) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        String key = item.getKey();
        String val = item.getValue();
    } ~

Answer (score 2):

You can save selected `spinner` item position in database and next time set the `spinner` item by saved position

To get position:
`int position = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();`

For setting:
`spinner.setSelection(position);`

notice that you should call `setSelection()` method after setting `spinner` `adapter`

Comment: I wan't to save the key 'en' in database not position . That was my requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can create [custom adapter for spinner](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) to achieve this.

With use of custom adapter

- you will able to use your `hashMap` for key value pair.
- you can pass your custom view to change.

Answer (score 0):

> Populate Spinner

```
void populateRecordPerPageSpinner(LinkedTreeMap<String, String> map) {
        String selectedValue = PreferencesHelper.getSharedPreferenceString(context, Constants.PREF_RECORD_PER_PAGE_KEY);
        List<String> recordPerPageList = new ArrayList();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> val : map.entrySet()) {
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(val.getValue(), "string", getPackageName());
            recordPerPageMap.put(val.getKey(), getResources().getString(resourceId));
            recordPerPageList.add(getResources().getString(resourceId));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, recordPerPageList);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mRecordPerPage.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mRecordPerPage.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getPosition(selectedValue));

    }
```

> Fetch and save position in preference

```
selectedRecPerPage = recordPerPageMap.get(mRecordPerPage.getAdapter().getItem(recordPerPagePosition));
PreferencesHelper.setSharedPreferenceString(context, Constants.PREF_RECORD_PER_PAGE_KEY, selectedRecPerPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated *Dhaval's* answer to be more generic. This solution utilizes `toString()` and `ArrayAdapter` (you do not need to implement your own adapter with all the logic) and is implemented in **Kotlin**

Create your custom class and override `toString()` method.

```
data class SpinnerEntry(
    // define whatever properties you want
    val label: String,
    val key: MyEnum,
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return label // this will display to user
    }
}
```

Initialize spinner

```
val entries = listOf(
    // you want to extract string resources to XML
    SpinnerEntry("LabelA", MyEnum.A),
    SpinnerEntry("LabelB", MyEnum.B),
    SpinnerEntry("LabelC", MyEnum.C),
    SpinnerEntry("LabelD", MyEnum.D),
)

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        val selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as SpinnerEntry
        val key = selectedItem.key
        // do something with selected key
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        // do something when unselected
    }
}

val spinnerAdapter: ArrayAdapter<SpinnerEntry> = ArrayAdapter(
    applicationContext!!, // get context depending on your implementation
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    entries
)
            
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter
```