# Assign values to string-array items in a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner in which I would like to select a state in the U.S. like 'Texas', and then capture that selection. I want the display on the spinner to be "Texas", "California", "Utah", etc, but when the user selects it, and I capture the value, I want the value to be '57' instead of "Texas". I know I can just do:

```
String selection = my_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
int selectionVal;

if(selection = "Texas"){
   selectionVal = 57;
}
```

But I would have to do that for a lot of states. Is there a way to do it like I explained above? If not, what would be the most efficient way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Better Approach to achieve by following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner/37046661#37046661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `HashMap` that contains the state name as key and it's equivalent number as value.

The after the user selects a value from the `Spinner`, all you need is to fetch the value from the `HashMap` and display it.

For example, you can try something like this

```
HashMap<String,Integer> myMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

myMap.put("Texas",57);
```

You can add all values to this `HashMap`.

Now when you get the selected option from the `Spinner`, you can fetch the value from `HashMap`.

```
selectionVal=myMap.get(selection);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **ONLY 3** lines of code. Save all your selection in **array** as following, then call them by spinner.**getSelectedItemId()**

```
String selection = my_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
int[] selectionVal = {57,58,59,60,61};

int sp_selected_val = selectionVal[my_spinner.getSelectedItemId()];
```

Comment: This was another valid accomplishing what I wanted. I chose another answer only because in my application's case being able to index a HashMap by state's names will be useful. Great and efficient answer!

Answer (score 2):

In your strings xml resource:

```
<string-array name="state_titles">
    <item>Texas</item>
    <item>California</item>
    ...
</string-array>

<string-array name="state_values">
    <item>57</item>
    <item>58</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

In your code:

```
String[] stateValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_values);
selectionVal = Integer.valueOf(stateValues[my_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] str=new String[]{"one","two","three"};

ArrayAdapter yourarray= new ArrayAdapter(MyActivityClass.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
   yourarray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   adapt.setAdapter(yourarray);

try this

Answer (score 0):

you can create enum for that:

```
public enum State {

    Texas(57),la(59);

    private int value;

    State(int value) {
         this.value = value;
    }

   public int getValue() {
        return value;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
   }
}
```

and then in your code you can fill spinner with enum value .

```
ArrayAdapter<State> stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, State.values());
    stateSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
```

and get int value like this:

```
int selectedState = State.values() [stateSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()].getValue();
```