# Can we store 2 values to a spinner?

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I am working on small app project that requires the user to select at least 5 different values from a drop down list, AKA spinner in android. My issue is I need to show user list of cities and then grab the ID of the city which the user has selected.

I have reached to a place where I can read the index value of the array in spinner and thus adding 1 to it I get the ID.
This link has the answer
similar to what I did,
[Set Key and Value in spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner)

but now the cities are called based on the alphabetical order (A - Z), and thus the IDs are no more starting from 1.

What I need to do is, store 2 values in a spinner. One will be the city ID and another will be the city name. Out of which only city name should be visible to the user. But only city ID will go to the database.

Please point me in direction of solution. Or anyone has any idea or work around this, please suggest.

```
String[] spinnerArray = new String[City_ID.size()];
HashMap<Integer,String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < City_ID.size(); i++)
{
spinnerMap.put(i,City_ID.get(i));
spinnerArray[i] = City_NAME.get(i);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>.   
(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String id = spinnerMap.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what have you done ? where is your code ?

Comment: I have edited and added the code. Please check.

Comment: The code seems fine to me. You sure it doesn't work ?

Comment: It works, but this is the old chunk of code. As per new requirement, I have to store 2 values to the spinner. Only one should be displayed and another should be read/taken to the database according to the selection. And can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended with a cutom spinner. I have a hidden EditText and then i put the city name in text view. The Edit text holds the city while text view shows the city name. I can access the selected city id from the array index.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, add your items

```
for (int i = 0; i < City_ID.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("id", City_ID.get(i));
    item.put("name", City_NAME.get(i));
    rData.add(item);
}
SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, rData,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

To get the selected item's name and id,

```
Map<String, Object> selectedItem = rData.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
String name = selectedItem.get("name").toString();
String id = selectedItem.get("id").toString();
```