# Getting the key of its selected child value in a Spinner using Android Studio and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the key of a certain child value by allowing the user to choose from a Spinner.

The Spinner has "Product_Name" values as its choices. By choosing one, the program should get its key and use it to get another child value for other uses.

Example:

PRODUCTS->
           -LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte->
                                Product_Name:"Steak"

By choosing "Steak" in the Spinner, I have to get "-LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte"

```
    databaseRefSelectItem = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PRODUCTS");

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = databaseRefSelectItem;
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //We create an array list to hold the values brought from the database and show them in the spinner
            final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                titleProduct = snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class);

                //populate the spinner with that array list
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTransactionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titleList);
                arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                selectProduct.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                titleList.add(titleProduct);

                //Click event for each spinner element
                selectProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        //pass the reference from that value into another snapshot in order to query those values, here you need to get your node id and inside just get your number , name and so on
                        selectItem = titleList.get(i);

                        mDatabase.child(selectItem).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {

                                key = dataSnapshot2.getKey();

                                currentItemStock = dataSnapshot2.child(key).child("Current_Stock").getValue(String.class);
                                currentStk.setText(key);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

How can I get "-LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte"?

Notes:
-LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte is randomly generated.

Comment: I'm trying to set my 'key' in 'currentStk' so I can see if it actually got the right key from choosing a product name in the Spinner...

Comment: Will it not be better to use HashMap of productID and productName instead of two reads as in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.getKey()` to get the key of the snapshot like:

```
for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class).equals("Steak")){
        String theKey = snapshot.getKey(); //This will return -LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte
    }
}
```

Will return key of the snapshot at that reference.

Comment: The app crashes and returns a null unfortunately... And the value of "Product_Name" depends on what is chosen in the Spinner, so "Steak" cannot be used to compare it all the time... :(

Comment: I changed the code a bit and managed to get the key of the last "Product_Name" value that the for loop has scanned, but still no luck. Only by choosing the last listed Product_Name does the key pop up, but only for that specific child value only. All other values return no key.

Comment: What do you mean by "All other values return no key"?

Comment: There are more choices than "Steak". For example if I choose "Chicken", the key of "Chicken" won't be found because the if statement only compares the last scanned value of the for loop to the chosen value in the Spinner. The key will always be that of "Steak", no matter what is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
Thank you as well to Yash Krishan for the code snippet :).

```
databaseRefSelectItem = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PRODUCTS");

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = databaseRefSelectItem;
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //We create an array list to hold the values brought from the database and show them in the spinner
            final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                titleProduct = snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class);

                //populate the spinner with that array list
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTransactionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titleList);
                arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                selectProduct.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                titleList.add(titleProduct);

                //Click event for each spinner element
                selectProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        //pass the reference from that value into another snapshot in order to query those values, here you need to get your node id and inside just get your number , name and so on
                        selectItem = titleList.get(i);

                        if (titleProduct.equals(selectItem)){
                            key = dataSnapshot.child(selectItem).getKey(); //This will return -LoUXnfUCEj4k4A3dkte
                        }

                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {

                                for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    if (snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class).equals(selectItem)){
                                        key = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                                    }
                                    keyholder = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Current_Stock").getValue(String.class);
                                }
                                currentStk.setText(keyholder);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Happy to help :)