# I am trying to assign a custom value to an 'Item' in a 'string-array'

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to assign a custom value to an `Item` in a `string-array`. For example in HTML I can simply set a value to an `option` located in a `select` tag  But I don't seem to get it with a `Spinner` in android.
Example in HTML is

```
<select>
  <option value="22000">Holiday</option>
  <option value="2000">Swimming Lesson</option>
  <option value="5000">Hotel</option>
  <option value="6000">Tickets</option>
</select>
```

My String Array

```
string-array name="vehicle_type">
        <item>Choose Vehicle Type...</item>
        <item>Trailers</item>
        <item>Trucks</item>
        <item>Scooter</item>
        <item>Bus</item>
        <item>Bikes</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="values">
        <item>null</item>
        <item>2000</item>
        <item>1000</item>
        <item>8000</item>
        <item>1800</item>
        <item>1400</item>
    </string-array>
```

I want to assign the corresponding values to the vehicle_type and also return the value as the result of the selected item

Comment: This question is already discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner

Comment: I checked it already but it wasn't clear enough

Comment: You better watch some YouTube videos as well about it.