# How to open/populate alert dialog box when Edittext gains focus android by disabling user keyboard

Tags: android

I have created alert box for choosing location from the list of locations. Below is the code

```
location_ele.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
               builder.setTitle("Select Location");
               CharSequence[] cs = locations.toArray(new CharSequence[locations.size()]);
               builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       // the user clicked on colors[which]

                       location_ele.setText(locations.get(which));
                       location = locationsId.get(which).toString();
                   }
               });
                builder.show();
           }
       });
```

Observe the code i have implemented this with `onClick Listener` it works only `onClick` but needs to work `onFocus` also .How can i do this??

[image: Screen]

You can see the screenshot Cursor is blinking, `AlertDialog` populated and user keyboard also populated. I only need popup to choose to restrict the user to enter text manually. Something happens for `datepicker` also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not taking any input from the keyboard, I the widget you are looking for is a [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), rather than an `EditText`

Comment: Yes , Can i assign array list to spinner @ihsan

Comment: absolutely! Please see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820803/android-spinner-using-arrayliststring

Comment: But can i do this with key paired means suppose  "XYZ" location is selected that corresponding unique id has to be sent to server when submit @ihsan

Comment: You can use a `Hashmap` and get the ID against the selected item of the spinner.
For references please look at these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656102/spinner-with-key-value-pair
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner

Answer (score 0):

it will help you.

```
        editText.setClickable(true);
        editText.setKeyListener(null);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final CharSequence[] items = {
                        "Rajesh", "Mahesh", "Vijayakumar"
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                //builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"text1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        });
```